# Swift runtime - calling superclass method

Tags: swift, objective-c-runtime

I'm creating a subclass of UIView in runtime and providing my implementation of the `layoutSubviews` method for it. One imporant thing that I need to do is to perform `super.layoutSubviews()`. In Objective-C I can do it using the `objc_msgSendSuper` function:

```
Class objectClass = object_getClass(object);
Class superclass = class_getSuperclass(objectClass);

struct objc_super superInfo;
superInfo.receiver = object;
superInfo.super_class = superclass;
typedef void *(*ObjCMsgSendSuperReturnVoid)(struct objc_super *, SEL);
ObjCMsgSendSuperReturnVoid sendMsgReturnVoid = (ObjCMsgSendSuperReturnVoid)objc_msgSendSuper;
sendMsgReturnVoid(&superInfo, @selector(layoutSubviews));
```

But `objc_msgSendSuper` method is unavailable in Swift. What should I use for performing the same thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[As Martin says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54002375/swift-runtime-calling-superclass-method/54006381#comment94849633_54006381), `objc_msgSendSuper` isn't available in Swift because it's a C variadic function, which Swift doesn't import due to the lack of type safety.

One alternative is to use [`class_getMethodImplementation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418811-class_getmethodimplementation) in order to get a pointer to the function to call for a selector on a given class type. From there, you can cast it to a function type which Swift can call using `unsafeBitCast`, taking care that the parameter and return types match up.

For example:

```
import Foundation

class C {
  @objc func foo() {
    print("C's foo")
  }
}

class D : C {
  override func foo() {
    print("D's foo")
  }
}

let d = D()

let superclass: AnyClass = class_getSuperclass(type(of: d))!
let selector = #selector(C.foo)

// The function to call for a message send of "foo" to a `C` object.
let impl = class_getMethodImplementation(superclass, selector)!

// @convention(c) tells Swift this is a bare function pointer (with no context object)
// All Obj-C method functions have the receiver and message as their first two parameters
// Therefore this denotes a method of type `() -> Void`, which matches up with `foo`
typealias ObjCVoidVoidFn = @convention(c) (AnyObject, Selector) -> Void

let fn = unsafeBitCast(impl, to: ObjCVoidVoidFn.self)
fn(d, selector) // C's foo
```

Note that like `objc_msgSendSuper` this assumes that the return type bridged to Obj-C is layout compatible with a pointer. This is true in most cases (including yours), but wouldn't be true for a method returning a type such as `CGRect`, which is represented in Obj-C using a C structure type.

For those cases, you would need to use `class_getMethodImplementation_stret` instead:

```
import Foundation

class C {
  @objc func bar() -> CGRect {
    return CGRect(x: 2, y: 3, width: 4, height: 5)
  }
}

class D : C {
  override func bar() -> CGRect {
    return .zero
  }
}

let d = D()

let superclass: AnyClass = class_getSuperclass(type(of: d))!
let selector = #selector(C.bar)
let impl = class_getMethodImplementation_stret(superclass, selector)!

typealias ObjCVoidVoidFn = @convention(c) (AnyObject, Selector) -> CGRect

let fn = unsafeBitCast(impl, to: ObjCVoidVoidFn.self)
let rect = fn(d, selector)
print(rect) // (2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0)
```

The distinction between `class_getMethodImplementation` and `class_getMethodImplementation_stret` is due to the difference in calling convention – a word sized type can be passed back through a register, however a structure of larger size needs to be passed back indirectly. This matters for `class_getMethodImplementation` because it could pass back a thunk for message forwarding in the case where the object doesn't respond to the selector.

Another option is to use `method_getImplementation`, which doesn't perform message forwarding and therefore doesn't need to distinguish between stret and non-stret.

For example:

```
let impl = method_getImplementation(class_getInstanceMethod(superclass, selector)!)
```

However bear in mind that [the documentation notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418811-class_getmethodimplementation):

> `class_getMethodImplementation` may be faster than `method_getImplementation(class_getInstanceMethod(cls, name))`.

Comment: Just as an additional remark: objc_msgSend(Super) is not available in Swift because it takes a variable argument list. There may be workarounds for this problem, but your approach looks simpler and safer: you don't have to think about objc_msgSendSuper vs objc_msgSendSuper_stret vs objc_msgSendSuper_fpret ...

Comment: @MartinR Yup – although that being said, you would have to use `class_getMethodImplementation_stret` instead if the method being called returned a structure (this appears to be due to the fact that it could return a thunk for message forwarding in the case where the object doesn't respond to the selector). Though it looks like this distinction is made automatically if you use `class_getMethodImplementation` instead. I'll add a note to my answer regarding this.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that class_getMethodImplementation has those variants as well ...

Comment: @MartinR What's weird is that there's no `class_getMethodImplementation_fpret` ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: (Unrelated to this question: Did you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/54283053/1187415?)

Comment: @MartinR Yes! I was going to write an answer, but never got round to it (I have exams going on at the moment). Essentially the answer is https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution-announce/2017-June/000386.html though, if you want to go ahead and write an answer yourself (I don’t mind if you do) :)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I “knew” that I had seen that somewhere but hadn't found it yet. I'm busy right now, I'll see if I can answer it later. – Good luck with your exams!